# Issue with Spring boot Controller with Mockito test case

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, dto

I am completely new to Mockito and I have to write a test case for my REST Controller, but I am not sure where should I start. Any help would be really appreciated.I've updated my controller based on given suggestion.

Here's my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {
@Autowired
TestService _testService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getsearchDetailCourse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<TestDto> getsearchDetailCourse(@RequestParam("courseName") String courseName,
                                             @RequestParam("courseId") Long courseId) throws Exception {      
    return (List<TestDto>) _testService.searchDetailCourse(courseName, courseId);

}
}
```

My TestDto:

```
public class TestDto {
    private String numberOfCourse;
    private Long courseId;

    public TestDto(){}

    public TestDto(String numberOfCourse,Long courseId ){
        super();
        this.numberOfCourse = numberOfCourse;
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getNumberOfCourse() {
        return numberOfCourse;
    }

    public void setNumberOfCourse(String numberOfCourse) {
        this.numberOfCourse = numberOfCourse;
    }

    public Long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(Long courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TestController.class, secure = false)
public class TestMethod {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;

    TestDto testDto = new testDto("Test",2744L);

    @Test
    public void retrieveDetailsForCourse() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(
            testService.searchDetailCourse(Mockito.anyString(),
                    ,Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(testDto);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/api/getsearchDetailCourse").accept(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        System.out.println(result.getResponse());
        String expected = "[{\"numberOfCourse\":\"Testing1\",\"courseId\":2744},{\"numberOfCourse\":\"Testing2\",\"courseId\":2744}]";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse()
            .getContentAsString(), false);
    }
}
```

I want to test the controller, please help me correct the test case above.

Comment: You're missing the whole point of Spring, which is *dependency injection*. You must NOT do `new TestService()`. Instead, you must tell Spring to inject a TestService into your controller. That's what will allow injecting a mock TestService in your test (among several benefits). It's currently impossible, since every time you call your method, it creates a new TestService, and will thus never use any mock.

Comment: I've updated my controller  but my test method is not working, please assist

Comment: You need to define "not working", precisely. That said, you make your service returns a single DTO, and you expect to receive a JSON array containing two DTOs. How could that work? And why does it even compile? If the service is supposed to return a list, its return type should be List<TestDto>, and making it return a single DTO shouldn't even compile.